# White strip at top margin in div center

Tags: css, html

when i position this div to the center and added a margin-top of 15px i got this white strip above the white div block. How do i get rid of it so that the white div is separated away from the top margin?

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
```

}

```
#middle {
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    width:750px;
    height:750px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bigbg {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-100;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    margin-left:0%;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/backgroundmain.jpg" id="bigbg">
<div id='middle'>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

add `top: 0;` to your id #bigbg.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Kp5z/)

Comment: If this answer solved your question you can check it to show others which solution worked for you.